# Async WCF-call slow on Windows Phone 7

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, basichttpbinding

I'm trying to write a small WCF-service (self hosted basicHttp) to receive mouse coordinates from the phones touchscreen. First I tried to write a sync OneWay-operation but I couldn't get it to work with the phone. It seems I can only write async operations? Isn't a sync OneWay-operation almost as much async as a real async method? Anyway I got it working with the async operation-pattern. But. It's very very slow. I can get about one message through per second, maybee a little more. Is this to be expected or is there any way of speeding this up with async operations? I don't need it to bee async for any particular reason other then WP7 demands it...

Comment: How are you sending the data? How have you verified the issue is with the phone?

Answer (score 1):

WP7 only supports async operations, to avoid developers writing code that blocks the UI, and thus causing a bad user experience.

Having a app that sends the touch-coordinates (there's no "mouse" for WP7) seems a bit strange to me, what's it for? Also, are you sending on when the user is moving the finger(s) around or on tap, or for all of it?

Comment: Im sending touch-delta from the phone to move the mouse cursor on the pc. Ive tried a similar app by Logitech on iPhone and its very fast compared to my implementation. Im not sure how they do it.

Comment: I would assume they keep a raw socket open, and just sends the mouse data to the said socket. You're opening and closing a (http) connection for every single movement.

Comment: Thats is very likely. I just realized Sockets is supported in the new Mango-release. And I have one week left on my vacation! :)